# Probability of quantity of people in some predefined area

Tags: probability

Let's suppose that we have a big city having a form of a square that is composed by other little ones, let's say $n$ and it is symmetric. Its center lies on the origin and the density of people follows an inverse exponential pattern ($e^{-x}$): as far you go, less people there will be.

How can I calculate the probability of "meeting" someone, knowing the population and the area of the city and its little squares? Or just, how can I calculate the quantity of people within some of the $n$ squares.

I was thinking about integrating the predefined area and the integrand would be the density. Is that correct?

Thanks